# Script not working as expected, node_modules and $PATH confusion, packages not found

Tags: npm, dependencies, node-modules, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have cloned a Github project to my system (Windows 10). Others have cloned the project and installed without problem.

Using Visual Studio Code I am trying to run a script listed in `package.json` that checks for the presence of an appConfig.json (using path-exists-cli) and if it's not found it downloads it (using download-cli). Without being explicit the script is `npx path-exists-cli src/assets/appConfig.json && echo 'exists' || npx download-cli https://example.cloudfront.net/assets/appConfig.json --out src/assets`.

When I run the script from the integrated terminal (`$ npm run config`) it shows the basic info (`> {project-name}@0.0.0 config | > npx path-exists-cli {remaining script above}`), a couple bash windows quickly open and close outside of VSCode, and the terminal returns to the input prompt. I do not get an `echo` that the file exists (it does not) and I do not get the file downloaded to the directory. I am not receiving any kind of error messages. I have checked the URL being passed to `download-cli` and it directly downloads the `appConfig.json` file without problem.

If I run the first half of the script (the part before `||`) as a command in the terminal, it echoes `exists` - even though the file does not exist.

As far as I can tell neither package used in the script is listed anywhere in the `package.json` dependencies so I have now installed each using `npm install -g path-exists-cli download-cli`. I have checked my global `node_modules` directory at `C:\Users\{my username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` and both packages are there. If I run the command `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'` I see that that same path listed in the output.

If I try to run `download-cli` on its own, for example with `download-cli --help` I get the bash error that the command is not found. If I run `npm ls download-cli` it returns `{projectname}@0.0.0 C:\{project root} |_ (empty)`. If I run the command `npm root -g` it returns my global `node_modules` directory at `C:\Users\{my username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`. If I try to explicitly call the package with `node_modules/download-cli --help` or `node_modules/download-cli --help` I get a bash error that no such file or directory exists.

What is going here? Clearly I'm confused about something. I've talked to others who are able to run the script without issue and we're unable to find the cause. Does anyone have any ideas?